# How to export JSON list to Excel file

Tags: python, json, excel

I have json list like below, and I wanna export it into excel file using Python. Please advise.

Code:

```
dataInJSON = [{'ConfigRuleName': 'required-tags', 'ResourceType': 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack', 'ResourceId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789:stack/security-headers/7304ffb0-8629-11ea-899e-0a5afd1032bb', 'OrderingTimestamp': '2020-10-26 09:20:07.860000-04:00'}, {'ConfigRuleName': 'required-tags', 'ResourceType': 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack', 'ResourceId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789:stack/security-wells/f1924880-8311-11ea-9a26-0af77bd56d08', 'OrderingTimestamp': '2020-10-26 10:57:19.215000-04:00'}]
dumpJsonString = json.dumps(dataInJSON)
jd = json.loads(dumpJsonString)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(jd, orient='index')
excelWriter = pd.ExcelWriter(r + outputExcelNameBase, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(excelWriter, sheet_name='Sheet1')
excelWriter.save()
```

Data:

```
[{'ConfigRuleName': 'required-tags', 'ResourceType': 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack', 'ResourceId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789:stack/security-headers/7304ffb0-8629-11ea-899e-0a5afd1032bb', 'OrderingTimestamp': '2020-10-26 09:20:07.860000-04:00'}, {'ConfigRuleName': 'required-tags', 'ResourceType': 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack', 'ResourceId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789:stack/security-wells/f1924880-8311-11ea-9a26-0af77bd56d08', 'OrderingTimestamp': '2020-10-26 10:57:19.215000-04:00'}]
```

My expectation:
[image]

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aniu/projects/aws/boto3/resourceManagement/getNonCompliantByConfigRule.py", line 175, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(jd, orient='index')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1299, in from_dict
    if isinstance(list(data.values())[0], (Series, dict)):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

TIA

Comment: try with csv lib instead ExcelWriter

Comment: Thanks, I have already made csv works. Now, I need export the data into Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your code pretty works....

just pip install xlwt

```
dataInJSON = [{'ConfigRuleName': 'required-tags', 'ResourceType': 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack', 'ResourceId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789:stack/security-headers/7304ffb0-8629-11ea-899e-0a5afd1032bb', 'OrderingTimestamp': '2020-10-26 09:20:07.860000-04:00'}, {'ConfigRuleName': 'required-tags', 'ResourceType': 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack', 'ResourceId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789:stack/security-wells/f1924880-8311-11ea-9a26-0af77bd56d08', 'OrderingTimestamp': '2020-10-26 10:57:19.215000-04:00'}]
dumpJsonString = json.dumps(dataInJSON)
jd = json.loads(dumpJsonString)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(jd)
df.to_excel("./excel.xls", index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks Netanell, I got below error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aniu/projects/aws/boto3/resourceManagement/getNonCompliantByConfigRule.py", line 175, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(jd, orient='index')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1299, in from_dict
    if isinstance(list(data.values())[0], (Series, dict)):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Take care that I didnt use orient='index' in from_dict method. Please run the code as written here.